# Back wheel rubs against the back brake pad when riding

Tags: frames, fork, hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-pads

My aging 26" Nishiki 10 speed is still a great bike and ride and well maintained. 25yr warranty ended in 2009. I am 6'7" and 280lbs now and was 250lbs when I purchased it. For some strange reason now when I ride the back wheel pronates over left and rubs against the back brake pad and the fork. The moment I get off it's okay. What gives??? Has anyone had an issue like this?

Comment: Short comment: it seems it is an issue with the wheel, maybe the axle washers not having grip on the frame, maybe some spokes being not tensioned or broken, not with the frame. Check the spokes by hand, if they are all stiff.
And check for cracks in the frame in the rear triangle. An example of a dramatic and huge crack is this one: http://pardo.net/bike/pic/fail-001/frame-trek-1985ish-seat-tube-at-bb-IMAG0079.jpg but a much smaller, barely visible crack can be visible. And will quickly grow.

Answer (score 4):

If it's rubbing while riding, but not when you're off the bike, it's either a spoke tension issue as noted by @earlgrey, or, you could have loose bearing cones that are allowing your wheel to flop around. Either way, a dangerous condition that you should have a local shop look into.